# Why does "With x.Chart" generate a Compile Error

Tags: excel, vba, variables, scatter-plot

Another piece of the same graphing problem - VBA doesn't like how I'm creating the series even before naming the ranges. I have 4 more variables: `ChtL1Obj As ChartObject, ChtL1 As Chart, ChtL2Obj As ChartObject, ChtL2 As Chart`. I've written the following code (starting with L2):

```vb
Range("Q31").Select

Set ChtL2Obj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=1075, Width:=450, Top:=465, Height:=225)

Set ChtL2 = ChtL2Obj.Chart

With ChtL2.Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "QC Level 2"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = RngL2X
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = RngL2Y
End With
```

The problem is, the code will not compile. At the `With ChtL2.Chart` I get "Compile error: Method or data member not found".

Where's the error?

Comment: Because `ChtL2` is already [`ChtL2Obj.Chart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart(object)), and there [isn't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart(object)#properties) `ChtL2Obj.Chart.Chart`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly what GSerg suggested.

When you set ChtL2 you are referencing that ChtL2 equal to ChtL2Obj.Chart

```
Set ChtL2 = ChtL2Obj.Chart
```

So you need to change **With ChtL2.Chart** to  **With ChtL2**

```
With ChtL2
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
End With
```

Means the same of ChtL2.ChartType = xlXYScatter or ChtL2Obj.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter